# Mysterious space character in request/response headers Python Eve

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, eve

The reason I put request/response in the title is because I'm not sure if its a problem at the request or response.

I created a small restful API in Python with the framework Eve, which is based on the Python framework Flask. The API needs to be deployed on an apache webserver using mod_wsgi.

After deploying the API, by following this article https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/, I can successfully do a `GET` request via Postman but, unfortunately, a `POST` request gave me a `500` error.

**The exception occurred by processing the app.wsgi script**

```
mod_wsgi (pid=11774): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/example.com/app.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 1106, in __call__
    return super(Eve, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2453, in wsgi_app
    return response(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 701, in __call__
    start_response(status, headers)
ValueError: space character present in header name
```

The exception said that it's not allowed to have a space character inside the header name. 
But I don't understand where the space character comes from. I tried creating a request via cURL, because I thought that Postman created those space characters in the headers, but sadly no luck it gave the same exception:

**CURL code example**

```
curl -d '[{"username":"test","password":"secret","roles":["admin"]}]' -H 'Content-Type:application/json'  https://example.com/accounts
```

While looking at the error it shows that the problem occurred when creating a response, so it might be a bug inside the framework, but I'm not sure.
I searched for any similar problems but couldn't find any. I hope that someone can help me a step further or give me that right direction.

Below is some code examples like the config file I created for apache, the app.wsgi file and the settings.py for Eve.

**Apache config file**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess app threads=5 python-home=/home/user/env
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/app.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/example.com>
        WSGIProcessGroup app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**The app.wsgi file**

```
activate_this = '/home/user/env/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/example.com/")
from app import app as application
```

**The settings.py file**

```
settings = {
    'DEBUG': True,
    'SOFT_DELETE': SOFT_DELETE,

    'MONGO_HOST': os.getenv('MONGO_HOST'),
    'MONGO_PORT': int((os.getenv('MONGO_PORT'))),
    'MONGO_USERNAME': os.getenv('MONGO_USER'),
    'MONGO_PASSWORD': os.getenv('MONGO_PASS'),
    'MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE': os.getenv('MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE'),
    'MONGO_DBNAME': os.getenv('MONGO_DBNAME'),

    # Enable reads (GET), inserts (POST) and DELETE for resources/collections
    'RESOURCE_METHODS': ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],

    # Enable reads (GET), edits (PATCH), replacements (PUT) and deletes of
    # individual items
    'ITEM_METHODS': ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],

    'PUBLIC_METHODS': ['GET'],
    'PUBLIC_ITEM_METHODS': ['GET'],

    'AUTH_FIELD': 'user_id',

    'JWT_SECRET': os.getenv('SECRET'),
    'JWT_ISSUER': os.getenv('APP_URL') + '/token',
    'JWT_ROLES_CLAIM': 'roles',

    'DOMAIN': DOMAIN,
}
```

**Example of a domain file called accounts.py**

```
schema = {
    'username': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
        'unique': True,
        },
    'password': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
    },
    'roles': {
        'type': 'list',
        'allowed': ['user', 'admin'],
        'required': True,
    },
}

accounts = {
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field': 'username',
    },
    'cache_control': '',
    'cache_expires': 0,
    'allowed_roles': ['admin', 'user'],
    'schema': schema,
}
```

Comment: Extra information. I created a custom route like this: `@app.route('/check', methods=['POST'])`. This works fine so the problem is in the domain of Eve. I will put an example of a domain called accounts inside the question.

Comment: Perhaps if you go that `base_response.py` line 701 and make it log the headers, that will give you a clue.

Comment: After logging the headers it seems like the problem occurred thanks to the module **eve-auth-jwt**: `[('Content-Type', 'application/json'), ('Content-Length', '91'), ('(\'WWW-Authenticate\', \'Bearer realm="app.eve_auth_jwt"\')', "('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')")]`. I disabled this module, so the line `('(\'WWW-Authenticate\', \'Bearer realm="app.eve_auth_jwt"\')'` won't appear, and it worked all fine. Thanks @dmitrybelyakov for your comment, I didn't think about checking that file. Now I will try to fix this by myself so I can still use eve-auth-jwt.